# Disable WCF headers

Tags: .net, wcf

How an I disable To, Action and all other standard WCF headers leave just body alone? If it's possible how client and service configs should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand fully what you're asking. Do you want to still use SOAP but just without any of the WS-Security and WS-Addressing stuff? Or do you want to just transfer the raw body XML without a SOAP envelope?

In either case, it's about using the right binding with the right config. In the first case, try the BasicHTTP binding with no message security. In the latter, I'm guessing you're probably looking at doing some form of XML-over-HTTP and WebHttpBinding is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. BasicHTTPBinding is exactly what I was looking for.